# Unable to connect to Oracle database using the JAR file

Tags: java, database, oracle

I'm using eclipse 2020 edition and I've added all libraries I need to connect to Oracle server like ojdbc7.jar and my code is like this:

```
public Connection SetDatabaseConnection() {
  writeInLog("Connecting to IRB", 0);    
        
    if(openConnection()){
     try {
             
                productionPool.setDriverType("thin");
                productionPool.setUser(username);
                productionPool.setPassword(password);
                productionPool.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(port));
                productionPool.setServerName(IP);
                productionPool.setServiceName(serviceName);
                productionPool.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+ _connStr.substring(_connStr.indexOf(":")+1));
                productionPooledConnection = productionPool.getPooledConnection();
                if (productionPooledConnection != null) {
                    //return true;
                    currentConnection = productionPooledConnection.getConnection();
                    logger.info("Connected to IRB server");
                    return currentConnection;
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                logger.info("Unable to connect to IRB server, SQLException: "+ex.getMessage());
                System.out.println(" (IRB-Exception) DB Exception: \n"+ ex);
                
            }
       }
  }
```

my problem is: i can connect to the server while debugging or running the application in the eclipse but when I exported a JAR file the application stopped in this step.

**in addition:**
my code to open a connection:

```
private boolean openConnection(){
        try {
            productionPool = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
            productionPooledConnection = new OraclePooledConnection(); 
            logger.info("openConnection(): Connected to IRB server \n");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("Unable to connect to IRB server , SQLException: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        logger.info("openConnection(): Unable to connect to IRB server \n");
        return false;
    }
```

The application never throws any excption it only write in the log file this statment: writeInLog("Connecting to IRB", 0);

Comment: Could you also add the stacktrace please? Could it be that ojdbc7.jar isn't on classpath, after you exported JAR file?

Comment: You're messing up the logging. You don't concatenate 'ex.getMessage()' to things, you pass the exception in verbatim, and let the log framework sort it out. This then gets you stack traces, causal chains, etc. You're tossing out 90% of the useful info. It's probably `logger.info("blabla", ex);`

Comment: when iIextract the JAR file I choose the option "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". and in addition, the ojdbc7.jar is in the Java build path!

Comment: @rzwitserloot that problem is it doesn't give me any exception the JAR file just exits. As you can see i write in the log file any case that would throw any exception but that never happens. as i said in the question it stops suddenly in the statement writeInLog("Connecting to IRB", 0); so this is the last line in the log file!!

Comment: The application runs fine when debugging or running inside eclipse but never works explicitly!!

Comment: @rzwitserloot, i did the change you suggested but it never reaches the exception!

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina, after exporting the JAR file i found this warning message: Fat jar  Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'E:JDBC/ojdbc7.jar' !!! why is that it was working before!! any idea?!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the exact reason why this happened but I removed the JARs that cause the error FAT Jar Export: couldn't find the class-path for ...etc and import them again. It worked successfully.